# Python script to print parent and child process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below parent and child processes spawned. First col is parent process and second col is child process

[image: Parent and child process]

I would like to print this in below format. Desired output: Each child process should be printed with \t\t followed by "=>"

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe
        =>C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe E:\s10.vbs
                =>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command $codigo =
                        =>C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe" "E:\s10.vbs, C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
                                =>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
                        =>\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe 0xffffffff -ForceV1
```

I created two lists like below with 1:1 mapping like first element of parent_process created first element of child process and so on. Then created a dictionary with empty list as values and then populate the parent and child process

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
parent_proces = [r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe", r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe E:\s10.vbs", r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command $codigo =", r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command $codigo =", r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass"]
child_process = [r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WScript.exe E:\s10.vbs", r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command $codigo =", r"\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe 0xffffffff -ForceV1", r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass", r"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe"]

tree_dic = defaultdict(list)              
for (parent, child) in zip(parent_proces, child_process):
        tree_dic[parent].append(child)

pprint(tree_dic)
```

I am getting below ouput

```
            {'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Thunderbird\\thunderbird.exe': ['C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WScript.exe '
                                                                         'E:\\s10.vbs'],
             'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WScript.exe E:\\s10.vbs': ['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe '
                                                                '-command '
                                                                '$codigo ='],
             'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass': ['C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\RegAsm.exe'],
             'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -command $codigo =': ['\\??\\C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\conhost.exe '
                                                                                                   '0xffffffff '
                                                                                                   '-ForceV1',
                                                                                                   'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe '
                                                                                                   '-windowstyle '
                                                                                                   'hidden '
                                                                                                   '-executionpolicy '
                                                                                                   'bypass']})
```

Now I need to print this as desired ouput. Anyone can point to the logic of this

Comment: You have to build a tree structure of the relationships first and then print it.

Comment: `zip()` is doing exactly what it should: pairing the first item in `parent_proces` with the first item in `child_process`, then pairing the second item in `parent_proces` with the second item in `child_process`, and so on.  If that is not what you wanted, then you will need to explain more.

Comment: It's unclear how to interpret `parent_proces` and `child_proces`. Surely there can be duplicates in either list, since multiple processes can be started with the same command line - how would you tell them apart? How would you avoid cycles? Instead of using two lists, you should probably tell us how you come by these lists to begin with a pick a better data structure first, before worrying about how to print the contents.

Comment: if your structure is tree-oriented, you can use recursion to print it. Each recursion level can increase the indentation amount.

Comment: I just updated the questions to put more clarification. First col is parent process and second col is child process. I just put both colms into two list.  There is 1:1 mapping like first element of parent_process created first element of child process and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well zip works this way...

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

for _a, _b in zip(a, b):
   print(_a, _b)

# will get output like

1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 0
```

I do not exactly understand what you need but.

```
parent_l = [...]
child_l = [...]

desired_d = dict()
for I, PARENT in enumerate(parent_l):
   desired_d[PARENT] = list()
   for CHILD in child_l[I:]:
      desired_d[PARENT].append(CHILD)

# Now you can I guess simply print it (or how ever you want)
for I, i in enumerate(desired_d.keys()):
   print('\t'*I + i)
```

**EDIT:**

```
for I, i in enumerate(desired_d.keys()):
   print('\t'*I + f'{i}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But looks like I am getting error on print statement.     print('\t'*I + i)
          ~~~~~~~^~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Take a look at the edit.